# I am trying to connect log analytics with notebook using this command %kql loganalytics://workspace='workspaceid';appkey='primarykey';alias=''

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kqlmagic

I am getting an error KqlError: {"error":{"message":"Valid authentication was not provided","code":"AuthorizationRequiredError","correlationId":"85bd6a1c-b7a0-4004-a0a0-ba2c7fd9432b","innererror":{"code":"UnsupportedKeyError","message":"The given API Key is not valid for the request"}}

I checked in log analytics workspace agent tab and see that only workspaceid and primary key are available. So I used that for authorization.

Comment: Same issue. Please comment your answer if you fixed it